# Change colour of progress bar if value is larger than 50 Bootstrap-Vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Trying to change the colour of progress bar dynamically using v-bind (don't have to use it).
Here is my code:

```
<b-progress height={} v-model="item.value.value" class="progress-xs" variant="{ 'success': item.value.value > 50,  'warning': item.value.value > 30, 'danger': item.value.value > 10}"></b-progress>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ittus's answer is pretty close, but it didn't work for me.  I was able to get it working by dynamically setting color rather than variant, which doesn't appear to be a [progress property](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/progress)

```
<b-progress 
  height={} 
  v-model="item.value.value" 
  class="progress-xs" 
  :color="getColor(item)">
</b-progress>

methods: {
  getColor: function(item) {
    if (item.value.value > 50) {
      return 'green'
    } else if (item.value.value > 30) {
      return 'yellow'
    } else if (item.value.value > 10) {
      return 'red'
    }
    return ''
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `:variant` and define custom methods to get variant type:

```
<b-progress 
  height={} 
  v-model="item.value.value" 
  class="progress-xs" 
  :variant="getVariantType(item)">
</b-progress>

methods: {
  getVariantType: function(item) {
    if (item.value.value > 50) {
      return 'success'
    } else if (item.value.value > 30) {
      return 'warning'
    } else if (item.value.value > 10) {
      return 'danger'
    }
    return ''
  }
}
```

Comment: I have pasted exactly that into my code and unfortunately it hasn't worked.
This is what chrome dev tools is displaying [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/t6TpFyI.png)

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can define custom method to get variant type.